# Creating an object instance that conforms to a protocol

Tags: objective-c

I've created a protocol (LEService) that I will conform to in multiple UIViewControllers. I won't know until runtime which UIViewController service has been chosen.

Is there anyway to create an instance of an object that conforms to a protocol without saying what the object is until runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
id <LEService> objectName = [self returnObjectConformingToLEServiceProtocol];
```

[`id`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Objective-C_Programming/in_depth#The_id_type) is Objective C's generic type.

Comment: @Denis just for clarification, you are not **creating** an **instance**, you are merely telling the compiler that the variable `objectName`, which can be any object, will point to an object that conforms to the `LEService` protocol. This could of course all be lies and cause your program to crash at runtime if the object you return does not actually implement `LEService` and you call one of the methods defined in that protocol.